# mining at 0 H/s

Tags: monerod, cpu-mining

I need some help please

I'm using a HP 6000 Pro Core 2 Duo E8400 3.0Ghz PC. The blockchain is fully synced and everything looks good, but when I issue a 'status' command in the running monerod, I'm getting this output

`Height 1422179/1422179 (100.0%) on mainnet, mining at 0 H/s`

I've started the mining process from my wallet with the command 'start_mining 2'

I'm getting some warning messages

`[RPC0] WARN miner src/cryptonote_basic/miner.cpp:305`

`[P2P1] WARN net.dns src/common/dns_utils.cpp:487 WARNING: no two valid MoneroPulse DNS checkpoint records were received`

as well as

`[miner 0] INFO global src/cryptonote_basic/miner.cpp:416 Miner thread was started [0]`

`[miner 1] INFO global src/cryptonote_basic/miner.cpp:416 Miner thread was started [1]`

Why questions are

1) Why is my hash rate zero?

2) Should I be concerned about the warning messages?

My thanks in advance.

Rob

Comment: The 0 report was a bug, since fixed. Mining was still going on, despite the wrong reported rate.

Answer (score 1):

I never used monero wallet for mining. 
try using a dedicated miner software instead.

I recommend the "xmr-stack" software.

there are 3 of them:
xmr-stack-cpu ( for mining using CPU)
xmr-stack-amd ( for mining using AMD GPU )
xmr-stack-nvidia ( for mining using Nvidia GPU )

They are free and open source. Link for the CPU one:

https://github.com/fireice-uk/xmr-stak-cpu

Read the readme for the installation & configuration.

Comment: Thank you for your response and help. Yes, maybe pool mining is the way forward; I'm just a little confused as to why my hash rate is zero.
To be clear, starting the miner from a wallet simply starts the mining process with the monero daemon(monerod) with a address of the wallet from which the command was issued.

Answer (score -1):

My colleague had this issue yesterday.

I noticed your processor (Pro Core 2 Duo E8400) only has two cores/two threads.

First try: 
start_mining address 1

and if that doesn't work, you should reprioritise the daemon process. Find the process id of the daemon and go to the command line (on unix) and write:

sudo nice -20 pidofdaemon